# How to fix this error ? Android Gradle Build Error?

Tags: java, android, firebase

Type com.example.recogext.BuildConfig is defined multiple times: /Users/soumyajitdey/Documents/Recogext/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/recogext/BuildConfig.class, /Users/soumyajitdey/Documents/Recogext/app/build/intermediates/javac/debug/classes/com/example/recogext/BuildConfig 2.class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 `BuildConfig` class. You need to delete one of these.

Comment: @SoumyajitDey if it's worked, you can mark this answer as accepted.